# finding gradient/curvature of surface defined by arbitrary, non-grid-spaced points

Tags: matlab

So I have a 3 dimensional matrix of points that (presumably) define a surface. For my purposes, X and Y can be random values but when plotted along with their Z coordinates, they will define some undulating surface. I'd like to measure the local curvatures of said surface, and in order to do that, I need to be able to find the gradient of said surface, at which point calculating the curvature is trivial.

I have not yet found an implementation of how to measure this curvature that doesn't make use of Matlab's gradient function. The problem with Matlab's gradient function is that it assumes that the points are in some sort of order, similar to diff(X). This would suffice if my points were spaced along a grid, which is not necessarily the case.

One possible solution to measuring the gradient is to give in and assign each point to a discrete coordinate in a grid in the XY plane, thus overcoming this issue. However, this solution seems somewhat inelegant and was curious to see if anyone had suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use griddata to interpolate from your scattered data points to grid spaced points and then calculate the gradient.

Comment: Thank you - that is what I was thinking in my 3rd paragraph, but this solution doesn't seem to be very good if the solution undulates wildly. I'd like to minimize the noise from the algorithm itself.

Comment: Did you find the best method at the end. I have the same problem and griddata gives large error especially close to points that follows a direction non following the x and y coordinates.

Comment: I was thinking to go for a least square but I am open to suggestions